# Receiving 'index_closed_exception' on asset/v1/content/assets/query when querying tags

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am receiving the following response on POST to asset/v1/content/assets/query:

> {"message":"Error retrieving asset collection: GetItemCollection: (400) index_closed_exception - Type: index_closed_exception Reason: "closed"","errorcode":30001,"documentation":""}

This is an API call that used to work (at some point in the past 1-2 years when I used to have a customer utilizing a particular feature).

The query in the body is:

```
 {"page":{"page":1,"pageSize":25},"query":{"property":"tags","simpleOperator":"where","value":"XXXX"},"sort":[{"property":"id","direction":"ASC"}],"fields":["id","tags","views","objectID"]}
```

When I make the same request, instead querying on something like customerKey, I receive the expected results.  For instance,

```
{"page":{"page":1,"pageSize":25},"query":{"property":"customerKey","simpleOperator":"equal","value":"XXXX"},"sort":[{"property":"id","direction":"ASC"}],"fields":["id","tags","views","objectID"]}
```

Top query does not work (and has in the past), bottom query does work.

Additionally, this same error is returned when querying against tags using a null check (again, this has worked previously):

```
{"page":{"page":1,"pageSize":25},"query":{"property":"tags","simpleOperator":"isNotNull"},"sort":[{"property":"id","direction":"ASC"}],"fields":["id","tags","views","objectID"]}
```

I can find no reference to this error code or error in Marketing Cloud documentation.  Any insight appreciated.

Comment: It may be that `tags` is not a string data type, but an enumerator.  You may have to use a different simpleOperator in your query as outlined in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/assetAdvancedQuery.htm) (the last entry in the _Filter simpleOperators_ section).

Comment: @AdamSpriggs tags is an enumerator.  The documentation you have provided explicitly states to use where, as I have done, when working with enumerators such as tags.  This has worked in the past.

Comment: Oh, duh.  I was looking at the second example.

Comment: I did a retrieve on an Asset with a tag using customerKey.  The tags were returned as ID strings,  not tag names, as I was expecting.  When I did a subsequent POST with the ID, I was able to get a successful response.  Are you using the tag IDs?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I did try it both way, using the tag name (which did work long ago) and the tag ID (as a string) which has worked more recently. For my own sanity, I have just tried again using both and am receiving the exact same error.  Ie: {"query":{"property":"tags","simpleOperator":"where","value":"84"}}

Comment: I suppose your options are -- verify your API permissions or try your luck on a support case.  I'm not getting the errors you are, so it could be something with your stack.

Comment: I can second that in my testing environment querying by tag ID worked for me and gave an appropriate result.